# Protect all sheets in a workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I want to protect all the sheets in a workbook based on username, so workbooks will be protected from external use, whereas internally we can easily use. However, the code just always states that the line If ws.Protect = True Then is false, even when I know the sheet is protected...

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim strUser, Num, myCount, ws

    strUser = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName
    strUser = LCase(strUser)
    Num = CLng(Right(strUser, 6))


    If Left(strUser, 1) = "D" And Len(strUser) = 11 And IsNumeric(Num) Then
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Protect = True Then
        ws.Unprotect "password"
    Else
        ws.Protect "password", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, _
                        AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
    End If
    Next ws
    End If

End Sub
```

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the `ProtectContents` property, so

`If ws.Protect = True Then` should be `If ws.ProtectContents = True Then`

Comment: Thanks! I was so close, but yet so far away!

Answer (score 1):

`ws.protect` is the command to protect the sheet not check if its protected. You can use

`ActiveSheet.ProtectContents`

`ActiveSheet.ProtectDrawingObjects`

`activeSheet.ProtectScenarios`

in your if statements to check if the sheet is protected in any combination of these properties.

Look here for more info: 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/161245

Answer (score 1):

I just want to comment that your user name checking code seems like it will fail a lot:

`Num = CLng(Right(strUser, 6))` this will give error if strUser does not end with 6 digits.
What you want is `IsNumeric( Right(strUser, 6) )`
Actually, dont even use `IsNumeric` because for example `IsNumeric("1,234.56")` will return True.

`Left(strUser, 1) = "D"` this will be False because you convert the strUset to lower case with `strUser = LCase(strUser)` (unless you have `Option Compare Text` in the begining of the file)

You can shorten the check to

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim strUser$, ws As Worksheet
    strUser = Environ$("UserName")
    If Not strUser Like "[Dd]????######" Then Exit Sub  ' ? matches any character, # matches any digit from 0 to 9, and [Dd] matches upper or lower case D

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.ProtectContents = True Then
            ws.Unprotect "password"
        Else
            ws.Protect "password", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, _
                     AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting code, I presume using the [] means whether the D is a D or a d? I will look into this, mainly the point here is that internally, we all have very specific user codes.

Comment: Yes, `[]` matches any of the characters in it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx

Comment: Lowpar, remember to click the accept answer check mark next to the answer that answered your question (not mine)